# Twitter Bootstrap: Collapse an accordion div in a responsive design

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, accordion

I have a responsive layout where I would like to make a div automatically collapse on a mobile browser but not on tablet or desktop, (ie. when the screen is less than 480px, the div will collapse into a bar that can be toggled to open when clicked on.)
I am having trouble getting this to work (similar to to nav collapse).
Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps some variation of the [responsive navbar](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#navbar) technique could work for you.